# Understanding recursive calls until buffer is exhausted

Tags: c++, websocket

I have a Websocket client that sends a message to a server which echoes the message back in the form of buffers.

The code is as shown, with `websocket-client-test.cpp` as the "main file".

If we focus on the `ListenToIncomingMessage` and `OnRead` method in `websocket-client.cpp` (it's near the bottom of the file), we see that every time `async_read` gets data, it will call the `OnRead` function, and the `OnRead` function calls `onMessage_` (which is equal to `onReceive` function in `websocket-client.cpp`, `onMessage_` assigned as `onReceive` at the constructor) to get the data. But the message may be incomplete on the first read, and so the `onMessage_` receives incomplete data, and so the equality check between `received` and `message` in `onMessage_` should fail. But, this is not the case; the Boost test reports no errors.

I'm now confused as to when the equality check is conducted? Or maybe I have a wrong understanding on buffers?

websocket-client-test.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE My Test

//Need the following to prevent unit_test.hpp
//from dragging in windows sockets 1 headers
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

#include "../inc/network-monitor/websocket-client.h"

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

using NetworkMonitor::WebSocketClient;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(connect_to_echo_endpoint)
{
    // Connection targets
    const std::string url {"ltnm.learncppthroughprojects.com"};
    const std::string endpoint {"/echo"};
    const std::string port {"443"};
    const std::string message {"Hello WebSocket"};

    // Always start with an I/O context object.
    boost::asio::io_context ioc {};

    // Create also a tls context
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx{boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client};
    ctx.load_verify_file(TESTS_CACERT_PEM);

    // The class under test
    WebSocketClient client {url, endpoint, port, ioc, ctx};

    // We use these flags to check that the connection, send, receive functions
    // work as expected.
    bool connected {false};
    bool messageSent {false};
    bool messageReceived {false};
    bool messageMatches {false};
    bool disconnected {false};

    // Our own callbacks
    auto onSend {[&messageSent](auto ec) {
        messageSent = !ec;
    }};
    auto onConnect {[&client, &connected, &onSend, &message](auto ec) {
        connected = !ec;
        if (!ec) {
            client.Send(message, onSend);
        }
    }};
    auto onClose {[&disconnected](auto ec) {
        disconnected = !ec;
    }};
    auto onReceive {[&client,
                      &onClose,
                      &messageReceived,
                      &messageMatches,
                      &message](auto ec, auto received) {
        messageReceived = !ec;
        messageMatches = message == received;
        client.Close(onClose);
    }};

    // We must call io_context::run for asynchronous callbacks to run.
    client.Connect(onConnect, onReceive);
    ioc.run();

    // When we get here, the io_context::run function has run out of work to do.
    bool ok {
        connected &&
        messageSent &&
        messageReceived &&
        messageMatches &&
        disconnected
    };
    BOOST_CHECK(ok);
}
```

websocket-client.cpp:

```
namespace NetworkMonitor{
    WebSocketClient::WebSocketClient(
        const std::string& url,
        const std::string& endpoint,
        const std::string& port,
        boost::asio::io_context& ioc,
        boost::asio::ssl::context& ctx
    ):

    resolver_ (boost::asio::make_strand(ioc)),
    ws_ (boost::asio::make_strand(ioc), ctx)
    // need to use a list initializer for resolver_ and ws_ since they
    // don't have a default constructor
    {
        url_ = url;
        endpoint_ = endpoint;
        port_ = port;
    }

    WebSocketClient::~WebSocketClient() = default;

    void WebSocketClient::Connect(
        std::function<void (boost::system::error_code)> onConnect,
        std::function<void (boost::system::error_code,
                            std::string&&)> onMessage,
        std::function<void (boost::system::error_code)> onDisconnect
    )
    {
        onConnect_ = onConnect;
        onMessage_ = onMessage;
        onDisconnect_ = onDisconnect;

        resolver_.async_resolve(url_,port_,[this](auto ec, auto resolverIt){
            OnResolve(ec,resolverIt);
        });
    }
    

    void WebSocketClient::OnResolve(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator resolverIt)
    {
        if (ec) {
        Log("OnResolve", ec);
        if (onConnect_) {
            onConnect_(ec);
        }
        return;
    }
        ws_.next_layer().next_layer().async_connect(*resolverIt,[this](auto ec)
        {
            OnConnect(ec);
        });
    }

    void WebSocketClient::OnConnect(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        if (ec) {
            Log("OnConnect", ec);
            if (onConnect_) {
                onConnect_(ec);
            }
            return;
        }

    boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();
    ws_.set_option(boost::beast::websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
        boost::beast::role_type::client
    ));

    // Some clients require that we set the host name before the TLS handshake
    // or the connection will fail. We use an OpenSSL function for that.
    SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ws_.next_layer().native_handle(), url_.c_str());

        ws_.next_layer().async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,[this](auto ec){
            OnTlsHandshake(ec);
        });
    }

    void WebSocketClient::OnTlsHandshake(
        const boost::system::error_code& ec
    )
    {
        ws_.async_handshake(url_,endpoint_,[this](auto ec){
            OnHandshake(ec);
        });
    }

    void WebSocketClient::OnHandshake(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        if (ec) {
        Log("OnHandshake", ec);
        if (onConnect_) {
            onConnect_(ec);
        }
        return;
        }

        // Tell the WebSocket object to exchange messages in text format.
        ws_.text(true);

        // Now that we are connected, set up a recursive asynchronous listener to
        // receive messages.
        ListenToIncomingMessage(ec);

        // Dispatch the user callback.
        // Note: This call is synchronous and will block the WebSocket strand.
        if (onConnect_) {
            onConnect_(ec);
        }
    }
    
    void WebSocketClient::ListenToIncomingMessage(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
    {
        // Stop processing messages if the connection has been aborted.
        // Since this is a recursive function, don't forget to return!
        if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            // We check the closed_ flag to avoid notifying the user twice.
            if (onDisconnect_ && ! closed_) {
                onDisconnect_(ec);
            }
            return;
        }
        ws_.async_read(rBuffer_,[this](auto ec, auto nBytes){
            OnRead(ec,nBytes);
            ListenToIncomingMessage(ec);
        });
    }

    void WebSocketClient::OnRead(const boost::system::error_code& ec,
        size_t nBytes)
        {
            if (ec) {
                return;
            }
            std::string message {boost::beast::buffers_to_string(rBuffer_.data())};
            rBuffer_.consume(nBytes);
            if (onMessage_) {
                onMessage_(ec, std::move(message));
            }
        }

    void WebSocketClient::Send(
        const std::string& message,
        std::function<void (boost::system::error_code)> onSend
    )
    {
        ws_.async_write(boost::asio::buffer(message),[onSend](auto ec, auto nBytesTransferred){
            if (onSend)
            {
                onSend(ec);
            }
        });
    }

    void WebSocketClient::Close(
        std::function<void (boost::system::error_code)> onClose
    )
    {
        ws_.async_close(boost::beast::websocket::close_code::none,[onClose](auto ec){
            if (onClose)
            {
                onClose(ec);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: your message is likely arriving in a single packet so the first call to `async_read` returns the whole message

Comment: @AlanBirtles What would happen if my message arrives in multiple packets? Would the callback wait until the message is complete or would it just perform the equality check and fails?